# Blender 2.9 installation Error 2753

Tags: error

I tried installing Blender 2.9, but this halts at this message 'Error 2753', searched the forums, seems this was an error back in the days of XP.

CPU Ryzen 3950X 32 threads (Liquid Cooled, 140x300 Radiator, 2x 140mm fans)
32Gb G-Skill Neo 3600 Ram, using XMP 2.0 profile gives CL15-15-15-39 (4x8GB)
RX 5700 XT Gigabyte GC 8Gb DDR6 Ram
Sabrent Rocket NVMe 1Tb M2 Storage
Asrock X570 Steel Legends MB
Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

All drivers etc are 100% up to date.

Comment: You probably have a blender folder already in your TEMPORARY files (happens to me once). Try to use the portable version of Blender https://www.blender.org/download/ if that works, then you need some tech support for your OS.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, I'll try a better clean up of blender, see if that works.

Comment: Hmm, cleaned up every trace of Blender from the system, I was already using the portable version installer.. same error.